# How to filter rows in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-core

How to filter movies with title, rating, duration and genre at same time, I mean there is no any functionality like SQL IN in LINQ. So How can we do that ?

Comment: The Title for a question isn't for tags; it's for giving an introductions of your question. I suggest you read the [tour]; you were prompted to do so when you signed up, and you did not.

Comment: Doing some tasks usually require doing several steps, we lack information on an actual problem.

Comment: use the normal LAMBDA Where method movies.Where(movie => movie.Title == "your title" && movie.Rating >= 5 && movie.Duration > 90).ToList()

Comment: "_there is no any functionality like SQL IN in LINQ_" you cannot write filters in string variables typing `WHERE conditions` because you could misstype, it is fas better if you are using EF or Linq to take advantage of the existing `Where()` functions. You avoid potential errors.

Answer (score 4):

I have made an **example** for you, you can try it

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Movies = new ObservableCollection<Movie>
            {
                new() {Title = "A", Rating = 6, Duration = 50, Genre = "B"},
                new() {Title = "A", Rating = 8, Duration = 100, Genre = "B"},
            };
            FilterMovies();
        }
        public void FilterMovies()
        {
            var selectedMovies = Movies.Where(m => m.Title == "A" && m.Rating > 5 && m.Duration > 60 && m.Genre == "B").ToList();
        }
    }

    public class Movie
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double Rating { get; set; }
        public double Duration { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
    }
```